# Is there a way to overflow a "list" of divs horizontally?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIcgp.png)

I want the second title card to be inline with the first no matter the display size. The way I expect this to work is for a scrollbar to appear or something of the sort.

This is my CSS for now (.mainCard is display: inline):

```
.trending {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.mainCard {
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

I tried using `white-space: nowrap;` but that just overflows the text and not the cards themselves.

[The result of white-space: nowrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL2HL.png)

```
.trending {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mainCard {
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Not sure if this will be useful but I am using react-bootstrap
Thanks for the help!

Comment: display: inline-block instead of float

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure correctly understand your question or not, Do you want ***Movie Title*** and ***Description Text..*** to be inline?

You can use HTML tags like `<h1>{Title}<span>{Desctiption}<span/></h1>` or may like to use `display: flex` or `display: grid`. in any case, I think reading the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) is better.